# get result from different two tables with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many-through

I would like to get a result from the different table. I have 4 tables. Like that::
Products, Categories, regions, product_categories `Product.joins(:product_categories, :categories, :regions).includes(product_categories: [:region]).includes(product_categories: [:categories]).where("product_categories.region_id = 1").select("product.name, category.name").group("product.name, category.name")`

I am using The has_many :through Association

result must be
   product_name , category_name

```
1- Computer, Furniture 
2- Computer, Tools
3- Computer, Gadgets 
4- Mouse, Gadgets
5- Mouse, Tools
```

But I got Product model like

```
1- Computer, computer_id ....
2- computer, computer_id ...
```

How can we get only the results I want.

Comment: The relations between `products`, `product_categories` and `categories` are pretty clear. What I'm missing is the relation of `airlines`. Can you add more details? Also some important columns.

Comment: There was a mistake, not airline it should be region. Relation in the product_categories. region_id is just a condition.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this match exactly your columns but it should work. Also, it's not clear why you need to join four tables. Maybe I'm missing something. Anyway, at least can give you an hint. I'm using distinct, but change to whatever you need.

```
@products =
  Product.joins(:categories, :product_categories)
  .select('products.name AS product_name, categories.name AS category_name, product_categories.region_id')
  .where('product_categories.region_id = 1')
  .distinct


<% @products.each do |product| %>
  <p><%= product.product_name %> | <%= product.category_name %></p>
<% end %>
```

Comment: There is no category_name field in product table and also there is no connection direct relation.

Comment: @janet, `category_name` is an alias for `category.name` which is in the join table, not in `products`. This is because the join table contains two columns `name` one from `products` an one from `categories`. But this is just my assumption for not having more details. Consider to edit your question adding more details about your models and relations, so people can help you better.